# Re-use fancybox, destroy active instance, and re-call it?

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

Okay, so this seems to me like it'd be simple, but I cannot figure it out.

Let's say that you have a fancybox (using FB 2.1.4), with code starting as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("#Button").click(function() {
  $.fancybox({
   padding    : 15,
   href       : "#FormAjax",
   afterClose : function(){
    $("#Error").hide();
   }
  });
 });
```

Now let's say that you bind that like:

```
 $("#FormAjax").bind("submit", function() {
```

And then you continue that function, do many things, etc. Then, once that is all said and done, you have refreshed a div on the page, and include a call to edit what you have just done (thus, you want the same fancybox to re-open and all the code to be able to be re-run.

Problem is, as far as I can tell, jQuery sets the active parameter to 1, and it needs to be reverted back to 0 to be allowed to re-run.

I've read about removeData(), .remove(), .clone(), and .detach(), I've never tried these since I don't understand how to use them, and the example on jQuery website, I cannot make heads or tails of, or should I say, I don't understand how to extrapolate that type of a function to something different. I've also tried to wrap the fancybox code in a div and refresh the div with new JavaScript code (it works when I refresh it with new HTML, but it doesn't work when I try JS).

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: I faced a similar problem and couldnt find any headway to it, so had to reload the page using 

`...
$("#FormAjax").bind("submit", function() {

//do whatever you need to and then close fancybox and reload page.
...
parent.jQuery.fancybox.close();
window.location.reload();
...
}`